# Azure Alert not triggered WebHook for Azure WebJobs

Tags: azure, templates, alert, webhooks

I'm trying to find what is wrong in my Template Deployment for Azure Alert. I want to Send Email and triggered a WebHook in Azure WebJobs with Basic Authentification.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {

  },
  "variables": {
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/alertRules",
      "name": "tesTalert",
      "location": "westeurope",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "properties": {
        "name": "test",
        "isEnabled": true,
      "condition": {
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.ManagementEventRuleCondition",
          "dataSource": {
              "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleManagementEventDataSource",
              "operationName": "RunFinished",
              "status": "Failed",
              "subStatus": "FailedExecution"
          }
        },
        "action": {
        "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleWebhookAction",
        "serviceUri": "https://$myUserName:MyPassWord@MyWebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/WebJobName/run",
        "properties": {}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

i have also try with this template with email and it's working but not for the webhook. Maybe the problem is from the api version , so i try different version. Nothing happend.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": { },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "microsoft.insights/alertrules",
            "name": "ADFAlertsSlice",
            "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
            "location": "westeurope",
            "properties": {
                "name": "ADFAlertsSlice",
                "description": "One or more of the data slices for the Azure Data Factory has failed processing.",
                "isEnabled": true,
                "condition": {
                    "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.ManagementEventRuleCondition",
                    "dataSource": {
                        "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleManagementEventDataSource",
                        "operationName": "RunFinished",
                        "status": "Failed",
                        "subStatus": "FailedExecution"
                    }

                },
                "actions": [        
                       {
                        "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleWebhookAction",
                         "serviceUri": "https://$myUserName:MyPassWord@MyWebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/WebJobName/run",
                        "properties": {}
                    },
                    {
                        "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction",
                        "customEmails": [
                         "MyEmail@email.com"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I can't find what is wrong. thanks for your help.

Comment: Quick question, is it that the webhook url is not "deployed" e.g the webhook field is empty and email field is correct? Or is it that the webhook don't trigger the webjob when the alert is triggered?

Comment: Tanks for your answer. The Webhook don't trigger the webjob when the alert is triggered.

Comment: But when i call the webhook with postman, it launch the webjob.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft docs, webhooks from metric alert rules can only use token authentication.

**Authenticating the webhook**
The webhook can authenticate using token-based authorization. The webhook URI is saved with a token ID, eg.

```
https://mysamplealert/webcallback?tokenid=sometokenid&someparameter=somevalue
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-webhooks-alerts
And if you scroll down to the comments other ahve the same issue as you do, they even started a feature request with MS.
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602299-azure-alert-management/suggestions/19711606-enable-user-password-authentication-to-webhooks

Comment: Yes, i try the same and it was the same result.
So i try with Webhooks for Launch Runbook with this format : 

"https://events.azure-automation.net/webhooks?token=MyToken"

nothing happend